# Are these Listview or Scrollview with Panel

Tags: android, user-interface, listview, scrollview, basic4android

**IMAGE LABELED A** (https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCK91.png)
I saw these images in app and with the image I labeled A, I want to know if its a b4a listview or scrollview with a panel with an transparency, and an imageview to the right and label to the left. If it is, can you provide example code on how to implement it.

**IMAGE LABELED B:** (https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZE3T.png) With this images, i will like to know if truely its a list view and how do you add the ***>*** sign with to the far end right whiles the test is at the left side

Comment: The first one looks like a `RecyclerView` with translucent `CardView` items. The second could be done with a basic `ListView`, with `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout` items.

Comment: Thank you, but I want to know if we have something similar in b4a

Comment: Ah, gotcha. I didn't see the [basic4android] tag. Also, please don't use caps unnecessarily, especially in the title.

Answer (score 1):

The Image A is surely a RecyclerView in which they have used a CardView.
The Image B is not sure because RecyclerView and ListView looks similar but working is somewhat different. You can get the basic idea on http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html It is best approach to use RecyclerView instead ListView if you have more data to display. And also you can animate as you can.

Comment: Thank you, I have seen and read about the recyclerviewbut I want to know if we have something similar in b4a

Comment: Search for Videos on Youtube of SLIDENERD, check for Android playlist. There you can get the Basic Knowledge of what Android is and how to use it. Go step by step.